# Coping Rows above into blanks rows below

Tags: vba, excel, copy, rows

I'm trying to use a code to copy rows and paste the values in blanks rows below them. For example:

```
1  ----> 1
         1
2        2
3        3
         3
4        4
```

But when I apply this code:

```
Sub Copy ()
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
  Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]c"
End Sub
```

This works good when I try it myself on excel when I manually type in numbers or text. But when I try to run this on a client's excel sheet I get the following (I'm going to represent their rows as arbitrary numbers):

```
1 ----> 1
       R[-1]c
2       2
3       3
       R[-1]c
4       4
```

Someone has already posted a code that works great, but I'm curious as to why my code isn't working the way I want it to.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an equal sign showing before R[-1]c in the client's worksheet? It's possible the cells are formated as text.

Comment: Yes there is an equal sign as well. I forgot to add it in. You're right, it was formatted as text and when I changed it to general it worked. But how come it doesn't work on text?

Comment: As excel says when you are formatting as text: "The format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the cell. The cell is displayed exactly as entered."

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the cells are formatted as text, that's why the content of the cell is displayed as exactly as it is entered. In this case '=R[-1]c'

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is the Selection you used in your code.

The code will try to find the blank cells in the selection and if the selection doesn't contain any blank cells, the code will produce an error.

You may try something like this...

```
Sub Copy()
On Error Resume Next
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]c"
End Sub
```

Replace column A with the column where you want to apply that formula.